# How to get id of the item clicked from layout action in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-event

I am validating the EditText value by clicking anywhere inside the window. But for some buttons, I want to do something different from the validation functionality. How can I get the id of the item from the layout action. Here my layout is ConstraintLayout. Tried the below code but it's not working.

```
window_layout.setOnClickListener(new 

    View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   
    
                    switch (v.getId()) {
                        case R.id.btn_tech:
                            setButtonsVisibility();
                             break;
                    }
    
                       
                }
            });
```

Please suggest a better way to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing right now is adding the listener to the parent view. You need to set the listener to the individual views.

You can add a `listener` variable and add it to the different button views.

You can also iterate your constraint layout child views and setting the listener individually.

```
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btn_tech:
                    setButtonsVisibility();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= windowLay.getChildCount(); i++) {
        rec.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
```